# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when sorting array of three integers

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I am getting the above error when trying to sort an Array:

```
Array.Sort(myArray);
```

What I am trying to accomplish (Quick sort using median of three technique), as can be seen from the image below is fill an array with three integers from another array (first position,middle position and last position) sort the array by using the `Array.Sort` and then chose the median as a pivot (the middle element of the sorted array which is in position `[1]`)
[image: image of the array]

Why am I getting this error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`?

Note: This error is ONLY being thrown when the first array contains 20000 elements, less than 20000 the algorithm works normally
edit: Whole AlgorithmB code:

```
public static void AlgorithmB(int[] array, int start, int end)
        {
            int left = start;
            int right = end;
            int[] median = {array[start],(array[(start + (end - start)) / 2]),array[end]};
            Array.Sort(median);

            int pivot = median[1];

            while (left <= right)
            {
                while (array[left] < pivot)
                {
                    left++;
                }

                while (array[right] > pivot)
                {
                    right--;
                }

                if (left <= right)
                {
                    swap(array, left, right);

                    left++;
                    right--;
                }
            }

            // Recursive calls
            if (start < right)
            {
                AlgorithmB(array, start, right);
            }

            if (left < end)
            {
                AlgorithmB(array, left, end);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the AlgorithmB method. Does it call itself recursively?

Comment: I think you are looking in a wrong place...Show the full AlgorithmB code. It has nothing to do with the Array.Sort.

Comment: @Me.Name  , yes it does. Check updated for full AlgorithmB code

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Pleas check updated

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine Array.Sort failing in this way. A small, fixed size array is most efficiently sorted with a sorting network. See the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748749/fast-algorithm-implementation-to-sort-very-small-set

Comment: The stack overflow indeed occurs because of the the recursive calls to AlgorithmB. The size of the input array determines the depth of recursion, so that's logical, but just out of curiousity, is the algorithmb sort implementation, purely for trying out, or is there another reason for not using Array.Sort on the original array? According to the docs, Array.Sort uses quicksort for large arrays already.

Answer (score 1):

This method `AlgorithmB` calls itself recursively. Most likely that recursion becomes extremely deep, which (almost) fills up the call stack. When something tries to use just one extra stack frame or stack variable or similar, the exception goes off because the stack can't hold any more.

This does not necessarily mean that the problem is at `Array.Sort`.

Check the call stack to see if my theory is corroborated.

Comment: I think you are correct because the method is being called multiple times. How can I do so? Shall I clear the call for each array?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, Vladimir is right and it has nothing to do with the Array.Sort, but assumed it has, then you can replace it easily with some simple if-constructs. This should be a simple task, since you only need to find the pivot of three values(start, middle and end).

Edit:

There is also a small mistake in your pivot choosing:

```
array[(start + (end - start)) / 2]
```

I think, you meant that:

```
array[(start + (end - start) / 2)]
```

Edit2: A less favorable pivot could be responsible for more recursively calls ;)